# How to loop array of data from session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I stored multiple skill set at session. I want to loop this skills at view using `foreach`.

`print_r` results of session is

```
Array ( 
  [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1570270733 
  [mode] => 
    [designation] => PHP Developer 
    [notice_period] => 60 
    [skill] => Array ( 
      [0] => php 
      [1] => Laravel 
    ) 
    [cities] => Chatakonda 
    [username] => jira@fingent.com 
    [client_id] => 10 
    [client_user_id] => 2 
)
```

I need to get the skills in a loop from this session. I tried

```
foreach ($this->session->userdata('skill')->result() as $session_skill_row) {
echo $session_skill_row->skill;
}
```

It returns

> Message: Call to a member function result() on array

Comment: Try to echoing only `$session_skill_row` variable

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
1.

```
foreach ($this->session->userdata('skill') as $session_skill_row) {
    echo $session_skill_row;
}
```

2.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['skill'] as $session_skill_row) {
echo $session_skill_row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @igor's perfectly correct answer the third way would be

```
foreach($this->session->skill as $skill_row) {
    echo $skill_row;
}
```